# Qt ActiveX QAxObject format Excel cell comment

Tags: c++, excel, qt, qaxobject

I would like to format an Microsoft Excel 2010 cell comment (e.g. change font, boldness, ..)
using Qt 5.

I can add an comment to a cell using the following code:

```
QAxObject* cellRange = m_activeWorksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int, int)", row, col);
cellRange->dynamicCall("AddComment(const QVariant&)", comment);
```

I am also able to set the AutoSize property for the cell comment:

```
QAxObject* axComment = cellRange->querySubObject("Comment");
QAxObject* shape = axComment->querySubObject("Shape");
shape->querySubObject("TextFrame")->setProperty("AutoSize", autosize);
```

But I am not able to change "deeper" comment properties,
e.g. TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold.

After setting the cell comment, the command

```
shape->querySubObject("TextFrame")
```

returns a non-zero pointer,
but

```
shape->querySubObject("TextFrame")->querySubObject("Characters")
```

returns NULL.

How do I format the cell comments using `QAxObject` ?
Is there a description of the properties/subObjects for the different `QAxObject`s
accessible by `QAxObject`?

The following code does not have any effect:

```
shape->setProperty("AutoShapeType", 5);
```

Comment: Did you try dumpObjectTree() and dumpObjectInfo() to get more information?

Comment: Hi Siliconmancer, not yet, but I will give it a try.

Comment: The solution of Lol4t0 for the Characters problem works: I use querySubObject("Characters(int, int)", 1, commentString.size())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Probably the problem is that TextFrame does not have *property* `Characters`. Instead it has *method* `Characters`, but [it full signature is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195027(v=office.15).aspx)

   ```
   Characters(Start, Length)
   ```

   Qt docs [says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html#querySubObject) that you should specify full signature, so you should probably query value with

   ```
   shape->querySubObject("TextFrame")->querySubObject("Characters(Start,Length)")
   ```
2. You cannot set `AutoShapeType` to `5`. `AutoShapeType` is of type [MsoAutoShapeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862770(v=office.15).aspx) and aonly specified values are allowed.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862770%28v=office.15%29.aspx the value for msoShapeRoundedRectangle should be 5 (Rounded rectangle), therefore I do not understand why shape->setProperty("AutoShapeType", 5); should not work.
Can you give an complete code example how to set the shape to a rounded rectangle.

Comment: Ok, It looks weird, but have you tried `shape->setProperty("AutoShapeType", "msoShapeSnipRoundRectangle");` like in [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html#querySubObject) example. Or else it looks like `shape->setProperty("AutoShapeType", "5");` (with qoutes) should also work. If it does, I'll write an explanation.

Comment: Even with quotes the shape does not change.

Answer (score 1):

After browsing through the Qt docs, the [QAxBase dynamicCAll](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html#dynamicCall)
section showed the the way how to set the shape of an Excel cell comment
using a dynamic call:

```
QString comment("My comment");
QAxObject* cellRange = m_activeWorksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int, int)", cellRow, cellColumn);
cellRange->dynamicCall("AddComment(const QVariant&)", comment);
QAxObject* axComment = cellRange->querySubObject("Comment");
QAxObject* shape = axComment->querySubObject("Shape");
shape->dynamicCall("AutoShapeType", 5);
```

The value can be found from Lol4t0's link: [MsoAutoShapeType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862770%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Here 5 is used to get a rounded rectangle (msoShapeRoundedRectangle). Here comes the remaining code to change the text comment format:

```
QAxObject* textFrame = shape->querySubObject("TextFrame");
QAxObject* chars = textFrame->querySubObject("Characters(int, int)", 1, comment.size());
QAxObject* font = chars->querySubObject("Font");
font->setProperty("Bold", false);
shape->querySubObject("TextFrame")->querySubObject("Characters(2, 3)")->querySubObject("Font")->setProperty("Size", 24);
```